# If an IntentService object is processed completely and takes indefinite time, how will other queued up intents be processed?

Tags: android, android-intentservice

I have a Class ABC which extends IntentService. This class is called by a receiver class named DEF which extends WakefulBroadcastReceiver.

Whenever DEF class receives an intent, it calls startWakefuleService and passes the intent to the ABC class.

In the onHandle() of ABC class, the intent is processed and relevant information is sent to the server using callback.

At the end of the onHandle(), DEF.completeWakefulIntent(intent) is called to return the Wake Lock.

My question is about the following scenario:

1. My BroadcastReceiver class DEF, received multiple intents
2. It started multiple IntentServices through class ABC.
3. The first Intent Service makes the http request to the server, which takes lot of time to come back or does not come back at all.

Will the other Intent Service that are started be process or will they get stuck in the queue waiting to be processed?

The [documentation] (https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/IntentService.html) says that the IntentService objects are processed sequentially.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All requests to `IntentService` are handled on a single thread and complete sequentially. If a request blocks `onHandleIntent()` and prevents it from completing, further requests will never be processed.

There is only one instance of a Service. There is no such thing as "the other IntentService".

> All requests are handled on a single worker thread -- they may take as
>   long as necessary (and will not block the application's main loop),
>   but only one request will be processed at a time.

Comment: Thank you for your response. In my case, I am making an asynchronous call while doing a POST request, will my IntentService block the other objects till I receive the response from the server? In other words, how does it know when the processing is complete

Comment: I don't know the specifics of your project. onHandleIntent() will not be called again until previous call of onHandleIntent() completes. If you're offloading in onHandleIntent() to do something asynchronously there, then perhaps you shouldn't be using IntentService.

Comment: what marks the completion of onHandleIntent()? is the end of the method? or the completeWakefulIntent call?

Comment: Yes if you're calling it at the end of onHandleIntent.